# LINK ERROR in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, msdn

I needed help making sense out of the following LNK error which i am getting.

```
SwitchFunctions error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) ??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z) referenced in function "??$find@Viterator@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PBD@std@@YA?AViterator@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@0@V120@0ABQBD@Z" (??$find@Viterator@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PBD@std@@YA?AViterator@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@0@V120@0ABQBD@Z)
```

Comment: Consider formatting the output as if it were code so that it will add scrollbars and ease reading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you have included all necessary dlls or lib files in your project settings?

Such an error usually indicate that you have used a function which definition is found, but implementation is not. Usually in the case of external libraries, the implementation is inside a dll or a static lib. Failure to provide the dll or the static lib will cause the linking to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? This might be relevant for VS2005:
[Link error using a CString derived class from a DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309801)